# Tiling manager with a GUI?

Tags: 22.04, tiling

I have a ultra wide monitor running Ubuntu 22.
I want a tiling layout manager - basically something with a GUI I can use to create a handful of layouts and be able to switch easily between them.
I looked at i3, awesome, and bspwm but honestly that looks like a lot of work and I don't really want to mess with that.

Comment: Didn't try it, but https://hyprland.org/ looks fancy. If you try it, tell us. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat This looks promising. I tried to install it but ran into issues. Will give it another go and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using WinTile: https://github.com/fmstrat/wintile
While it has a single layout, you can easily move the windows through the grid and that pretty much covers 99% of the usecase I have.

Another extension that seems to do the same thing, but is a bit more complex (as in has more functionality) is Forge https://github.com/forge-ext/forge